# OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0': error 0x7e. Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locat 'gobject-2.0-e a libra

Tags: gtk

when I want to run the Django project, I encounter this error:
OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0-0'

I ran this script, but it didn't work:
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-gobject
pip uninstall pygobject
pip install pygobject